# How to properly add a "callback" parameter to Sencha Touch Ext.Ajax.request()?

Tags: ajax, jsonp, sencha-touch

I'm currently sending my callback as follows

```
var submitCommunicateCard = function () {
    //display Loading indicator to user
    console.log(rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.getValues());
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: WebService('GetInTouch', 'CommunicateCard'),
        method: 'post',
        params: {
            callback: 'foo', // THIS SUCKS!!!
            name: 'Test Name'  
        }
    });
};
```

Although this works, I'd prefer to have Sencha add the callback for me.

I tried this, bit it **did not work**

```
var submitCommunicateCard = function () {
    //display Loading indicator to user
    console.log(rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.getValues());
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: WebService('GetInTouch', 'CommunicateCard'),
        method: 'post',
        scriptTag: true,  //WHY DOESN'T THIS WORK?
        params: {
            name: 'Test Name'  
        }
    });
};
```

How can I properly add a "callback" to Sencha Touch Ext.Ajax.request()?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. So you are trying to make Ext.Ajax add the same parameter on every request?

Comment: No, if you look at the `Ext.Data.store()`, there's a parameter `type: 'scripttag'`. When the store polls an external web service, it automatically adds `callback=stcCallbackNNNN` to the POST data. By doing this, the web service knows to request JSONP. I'm doing a similar thing with form submission, however `scriptTag: true` doesn't seem to be accomplishing the same task.

Comment: this question has all the parts of a valid question as per the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and it still got a down vote. interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "you can't"

You have to use `Ext.util.JSONP.request();`

Answer (score 0):

Ext.Ajax generates two types of post-request events, requestcomplete and requestexception.  You can use `Ext.Ajax.on("requestcomplete", function (conn, response, options))` for successful requests, and `Ext.Ajax.on("requestexception", function (conn, response, options))` for failed ones.

Comment: not looking to do success/failure responses at this time, just trying to add the `callback` parameter to the POST request.

Comment: doesn't work.  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined